# How do you create a number sequence that displays two of each number in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, seq

How do you create a number sequence that will display each number twice?

Like so:

```
#0001 
#0001
#0002 
#0002
#0003 
#0003
#0004 
#0004
#0005 
#0005
```

I need to create a table where the same number is displayed multiple times in each row.

```
#0001  #0001 
#0002  #0002
#0003  #0003
#0004  #0004
#0005  #0005
```

I thinking there might be something like `{SEQ MyList  \# "0000" \*DUPLICATE_VALUES}`

I tried searching it but don't even know what the proper terminology would be.

Comment: Is there a reason why two list names (MyList1 and MyList2) wouldn't work for you?

Comment: @rich Probably not, in fact that would probably work pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's as simple as:

```
{SEQ MyList \# 0000}
```

and, for the duplicate:

```
{SEQ MyList \c \# 0000}
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!